# Compute numeric Pfaffians of matrices efficiently?

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, algorithm

I have the following code, that computes the [Pfaffian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pfaffian) of an even dimensional anti-symmetric matrix via direct row expansion:

```
drop[m_, parts__List] /; Length[{parts}] <= ArrayDepth[m] := (m[[##1]] &) @@  MapThread[ Complement, {Range[Dimensions[m, Length[{parts}]]], {parts}}];
pf[matrix_] := If[Dimensions[matrix][[1]] === 2, matrix[[1, 2]], Sum[(-1)^i matrix[[1, i]] pf[drop[matrix, {1, i}, {1, i}]], {i, 2, Dimensions[matrix][[1]]}]];
```

We can generate example anti-symmetric matrices like:

```
size=10;
mat = Table[ If[i > j, i (i - j), j (i - j)], {i, 1, size}, {j, 1, size}];
```

For `size=10;`, the function returns the Pfaffian quickly

```
pf[mat]
```

> `-10`

However, if I set `size=20`, the calculation takes forever and never finishes. Considering that the square of the Pfaffian is the determinant `Det[mat]==pf[mat]^2`, and determinants of larger matrices are still computed quickly by Mathematica:

```
size=20;
mat = Table[ If[i > j, i (i - j), j (i - j)], {i, 1, size}, {j, 1, size}];
Det[mat]
```

> `400`

I wonder if it is possible to write an algorithm that computes Pfaffians of larger matrices quickly as well? (I really need the overall sign information for the actual Pfaffians I want to compute, so I cannot fall back to computing determinants and square roots.) Thanks for any suggestion!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out, very efficient implementations have been written by M. Wimmer in the work

> https://arxiv.org/abs/1102.3440

In the section "Ancillary Files" to the right, click on "(120 additional files not shown)" and scroll down until you find the line "pfapack/mathematica/pfaffian.nb". This file contains a routine called `PfaffianLTL[]` which computes the Pfaffian incredibly fast (even for `size=200` it takes just a few seconds).

Comment: I was going to suggest something along the lines of using the built-in `LUDecomposition`, but hadn't worked out the math, yet. :)